# diffeomorphism in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, diffeomorphism

We have $$f:(0,\infty)\times (0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$$
$$f(x,y)=(x^{2} - y^2,xy)$$
How can I show this function is a diffeomorphism of class $C^{\infty}$ of $(0,\infty)\times (0,\infty)$ in a open set in $\mathbb R^{2}$?

Comment: Do you know what the requirements for a function to be a diffeomorphism of class $C^\infty$ are?

Comment: U and V are open sets in euclidean spaces, and $$ f:U \rightarrow V$$ is a bijection. So f is a diffeomorphism of U in V if f is differentiable and $$f^{-1}$$ too.
Of Class $$C^{\infty}$$ if I can differentiate infinitely.

Comment: Sounds like you have your answer to "how can I show this function is a diffeomorphism of class $C^\infty$." That is, find $f^{-1}$ then verify that over the desired sets, $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are infinitely differentiable; and of course verify $f$ (or $f^{-1}$) is a bijection.